# How to declare a function returning a pointer to an array?

Tags: c

How can one have a function returning a pointer to an array and what are the general things that one needs to keep in mind while doing that?

Comment: Usually, one avoids doing that; the declaration is hairy!

Comment: Is it allocating the array?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, nope, `int (*func(args))[]` is trivial, isn't it? :P

Comment: @H2CO3: I guess it depends on your definition of hirsuteness.

Comment: @H2CO3 Oh right, the actual function definition. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int (*foo(void))[4];
```

declares `foo` as a function with no parameters that returns a pointer to an array 4 of `int`.

For example:

```
int (*p)[4];
p = foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically a function would return a *pointer* to the zeroth element of an array.

```
int * f() {
  // ...
```

The trick is - who is responsible for the storage of the elements, the function or the caller?

Answer (score -1):

```
How can one have a function returning a pointer to an array
```

This function returns a pointer to an array :

```
  char * create_array() {
        char * array = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(char)); 
        return array; 
    }
```

However, if it is not strictly necessary you should avoid this practice.  For example, the previous example is **not** a good c practice because it allocates memory in the heap, but delegates to another function the responsibility of freeing it.

Comment: `void` is not a pointer to an array, nor is `char *`.

Comment: And no, returning a pointer to `malloc()`ated memory is not bad practice at all. Conversely, it's quite common and idiomatic.

Comment: Yes, I know! I forgot to write the return type :D

Comment: However, it depends on what you are doing. I think the caller function should be responsible for allocating/de-allocating the memory and the called function should only modify the arrays values. This should reduce the risk of having area of memory that are not properly freed.

Comment: Counter example: the `malloc()` and `realloc()` routines allocate and reallocate memory that is subsequently freed by `free()` (or `realloc()` — the all-in-one memory management function).  A little extreme, but not outrageously so.  Less extreme examples include `strdup()` and `asprintf()` and its relatives.  It is perfectly permissible and sensible to define a function that returns a pointer to allocated memory that becomes the responsibility of the called function to release.

Comment: I completely agree that sometimes is useful to let the callee function allocates the memory, and `strdup()` and `asprintf()` are  good examples. However, I am thinking of a large context where  several developers are working on the same code base, in this case, this practice may arise more then one problem because the knowledge of a developer cannot not be just limited to the interface exposed. To use correctly these functions, a developer should know how a function works internally and often they do not spend time doing so. 
I really appreciate your comments thanks!